# Using facebook sdk in android fragment

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i open session and get facebook data my activity that holds fragment suddenly pops up.
It looks like this :

[image: For the time that facebook data is downloading(2 sec) i am seeing this in my fragment.]

I get data and everything normally but for those 2 seconds that facebook data is downloading  all i see is my activity.

I have in my activity:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);


}
```

And in my fragment i open session like this:

```
 s.openActiveSession(mActivity, false, mCallback);
```

CALLBACK:

```
 private Session.StatusCallback mCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {

            if (session.isOpened()) {                             
              Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                        com.facebook.Response response) {

                    try {

                        editEmail.setText((String) user.getProperty("email").toString());
                    }catch(Exception e){

                        Toast.makeText(mActivity,"We couldn't retrieve your email because you didn't confirm your email!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    editName.setText(user.getFirstName());
                    editSurname.setText(user.getLastName());

                                            Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                    Session.setActiveSession(null);


                }
              });
            }

        }
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Too much activity in the main thread. Use an async task instead:

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request
       .GraphUserCallback() { ... }).executeAsync();
```